# Output Graph Change on LOF

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, elki

I am running local outlier factor on a data set called shuttle downloaded from uci. Every time i am run lof algorithm on shuttle data set with or without decision class but elki is drawing different output graph. I am confused what is the reason behind drawing different output graphs every time?

Answer (score 0):

The visualization uses Apache Batik, which requires both a complex XML document (SVG, to be precise) as well as Batik's rendering tree to be in memory.

This makes the visualization not very scalable, and there is the parameter

```
-vis.sampling
```

Which **defaults to a sample of 10000**. So on larger data sets, you will see a different sample *visualized* every time. It still uses all data for analysis, of course. It would be fairly easy to add a parameter to fix the random seed, but people tend to complain about too many parameters...

For variants of the shuttle data set more suitable for outlier detection, see this site:

http://www.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/research/outlier-evaluation/DAMI/literature/Shuttle/

Note that to correctly read the files, you will need the parameters `-arff.externalid id -arff.classlabel outlier` so that the id column is not used for analysis, and the outlier label column is used as class for evaluation only.

Comment: Thx bro for your reply. I have one more issue with Elki because with 50000 data points output graph is taking too long to create so i want to see output of LOF in just a text file. Is it possible in Elki?

Comment: Yes, choose the result writer instead of the visualizer.